# Building and coding a program to draw a rectangle of asterisks in visual basic

Tags: vba

I am trying to build a for loop that greats a rectangle with asterisks where a user can enter the number of rows and columns they would wish displayed. I am able to get the rows working correctly but I unable to get the columns to work as they should. Could anyone correct me on where am going wrong:

```
Private Sub cmdProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdProcess.Click
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim columns As Integer

    rows = txtRow.Text
    columns = txtColumn.Text

    lbloutput.Text = ""
    For i = 1 To rows
        lbloutput.Text = lbloutput.Text & "*" & vbCrLf

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm no good at VB but it looks like u r using `column` anywhere.

Comment: I suggest you consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com as you simply need a code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything else: your code will error if the user enters a negative number, or 0.  Unless you have any other code to address this, you might want to try something like this:

```
rows = Abs(cInt(txtRow.Text))
columns = Abs(cInt(txtColumn.Text))
if rows*columns < 1 Then Exit Sub
```

(If your code is in VBA, rather than VB, then there is no advantage to using `Integer` over `Long`, as they both use the same amount of memory — an `Integer` just locks half of it out as unusable)

A naïve approach would be to use two loops, like so:

```
lbloutput.Text = ""
For i = 1 To rows 'How many lines of text?
    For j = 1 to columns 'How many asterisks per line?
        lbloutput.Text = lbloutput.Text & "*"
    Next j
    lbloutput.Text = lbloutput.Text & vbCrLf
Next i
```

However, a simpler method would be to use the `String` function:

```
lbloutput.Text = ""
For i = 1 To rows
    lbloutput.Text = lbloutput.Text & String(columns, "*") & vbCrLf
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you Chronocidal 

my mistake was adding the output "*" on the outer nested loop. The "Next K" command is meant to repeat the loop on J until it has the meet the number of columns needed correct?

Comment: @FitzgeraldChambwa Correct.  For every row, it will loop through and add a "*" for each column, then add `vbCrLf` and repeat for the next row.  You can usually set a breakpoint and step through with F8 (rather than the normal Run / F5) to see each step as it happen ;¬)  Useful for debugging¬